# Use the shiftY method to set the y-coordinate of point1 to 9 in Java

Tags: java, points

For homework I need to set the point of a Y coordinate for an object called "point1" to 9. This is done in BlueJ IDE in the code pad.

I am given the following information after having created my point1 object.

```
public void shiftY (int y)
```

I have tried the following among many others and keep getting a ERROR: Illegal start of expression.

```
public void shiftY(point2(9));
public void(point2.shiftY(9));
shiftY(point2(9));
```

Comment: That's not how you call (or declare) methods. I really don't understand which of these you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you should read your lecture materials and/or some Java tutorials to learn the basic syntax and concepts of the language.

Comment: Yeah, I have read the chapters in my text 4 times now. We are using the "Big Java Early Objects 5th Edition" book. I can't find anything in the text related to shifting points of either an X or Y value (not both). I have also read some Java documentation, but we do not cover how to actually locate what we are looking for in the API till next week. This is my first semester of a programming class. The question does not state to declare or call a method. It just states exactly what is in my title. This is not done in a text file, it is done in the code pad and I can only write one line at a time

Comment: You will need to call some method if you want to set coordinates of `point1`, unless they are directly accessible. Since you are supposed to (are you?) somehow use `shiftY()`, you could just try calling it with argument `9`. That would be `point1.shiftY(9);`. If that doesn't do it, you should provide some information about the type of `point1` and the defined methods that it has.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it. I tried that so many times, but I tried          Point.shiftY(9);